# Error "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'" during tutorial

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Starting my training back up I arrived successfully at:
Using rqt_console and roslaunch

All previous lessons were achieved.

ROS' roscore command was entered into a separate terminal earlier.  Tests up to this point all work as directed by ROS wiki.

Now, at this point:

By entering "echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH" this command outputs to one of my Ubuntu terminals:

```
/home/ju78iklo9/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
```

While in ju78iklo9@ju78iklo9-Lenovo-H50-00:~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/launch$

I entered:

```
roslaunch beginner_tutorials turtlemimic.launch
```

Ubuntu terminal outputs:

```
roslaunch beginner_tutorials turtlemimic.launch
```

I get this response:

```
...  logging to /home/ju78iklo9/.ros/log/a29cb34c-e6b4-lle7-aa15-acb57d898fed/roslaunch-ju78iklo9-Lenovo-H50-00-6404.log
Checking log directory for disk usage This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Don checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB

Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: syntax error: Line 1, column 3
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Meanwhile...my "launch" file is/was copied directly from ROS tutorials. A vim "less" command reproduces:

```
   1 <launch>
   2 
   3   <group ns="turtlesim1">
   4     <node pkg="turtlesim" name="sim" type="turtlesim_node"/>
   5   </group>
   6 
   7   <group ns="turtlesim2">
   8     <node pkg="turtlesim" name="sim" type="turtlesim_node"/>
   9   </group>
  10 
  11   <node pkg="turtlesim" name="mimic" type="mimic">
  12     <remap from="input" to="turtlesim1/turtle1"/>
  13     <remap from="output" to="turtlesim2/turtle1"/>
  14   </node>
  15 
  16 </launch>
```

Opening the log file in vim produces an amazing laundry list of errors.  For example:

```
1 <launch>
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
2
2: command not found
3 <group ns="turtlesim1"
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

My questions is, "what is the problem? Why can't I proceed with ROS tutorials at this point?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278093/error-%22bash:-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-%60newline%27%22-during-tutorial/) by [ju78iklo9](https://answers.ros.org/users/32592/ju78iklo9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If what you cited is the actual file content of yours, you copied the line number index that ROS wiki kindly shows for you. By clicking "`Toggle line numbers`" you can make those numbers disappear.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2